# Do Django templates get cached in browser?

Tags: python, node.js, django, angular

Let's say we have a request made in Django  which renders `my_template.html`  and the context of `{foo: bar}`

```
 return render(request, "my_template.html", {foo: bar})
```

Now based on the user activity foo and bar change. Let's say if a user has made his first request. Django will return the template and the corresponding `{foo: bar}` based on user activity. Let's say if the user had made a second request with a different activity.

Will Django send `my_template.html` from the server to the browser or will only the changed `context` be sent to the browser? Does the template get cached in the browser?

> Case 1:

If the template gets cached in a browser if a code with some changes is deployed does it reflect in the client's browser? Does this work in the way where the md5 hash of both the templates is compared if they are not in sync then the template is downloaded from Django server?

> Case2

If the template is rendered every time for every request then does that mean the bandwidth usage is not optimistic?

I read that in a node and angular the javascript bundles is cached in clients browser and only data(`context {foo: bar}`) calls are made to a server so the bandwidth usage is better and loading is faster is this true.

Comment: Django templates are rendered on the server and a full page is sent for every request. But there are ways to cache even with server side rendering. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#downstream-caches

Comment: Bandwidth is cheap. Unless you have *really* good reasons to optimize for bandwidth up front, your time is better spent optimizing for developer productivity and application stability. No point shaving 5kb off every request if it takes you 3 times as long, and falls over all the time. You can always progressively add Angular/Vue/FrameworkXYZ later, when you actually know where the hot paths are.

Comment: when i mean bandwidth i am speaking about data  that gets transferred  between client and server this is important when internet connection is slow

Comment: @saitejapakalapati "Bandwidth" does not mean the data that's transferred, it means the speed of the data transfer. The "bandwidth" which you're talking about is a misnomer popularised by hosting providers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django is a server side framework. Templates are fully rendered in the server before they are sent to the client. As a result the browser does not know anything at all about the templates; only the fully rendered html.

But there's no point in comparing Django with Angular like this.  You can't use Angular on its own without some kind of backend framework, which could well be Django - the two work well together.

Comment: Thanks!. Read about django rest framework  and angular javascript bundles formed after transpiling . so if i use DRF and angular so that  these js bundles are cached in browser and now the server call will be for data service only hence the html files are not rendered always from server is my uderstanding correct.

Comment: You're understanding correctly @saitejapakalapati. If you are using DRF your backend is an API and you will fetch resources from it . Your client (in this case made with Angular) will consume resources from your API. :-)

Comment: @Daniel Roseman - So would you say that it is possible to do things such as "DOM Diffing" while using Django? That is what I thought of when I read this (e.g., in React.js).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the template will not be cached, or in the very least it will not be cached in any way that prevents getting an update.  Upon saving an update to the template there is an auto-deploy process that may take a few seconds (and you can watch in the command line if you have used the 'runserver' command).  After that auto-deploy is completed then the template will be served fresh upon browser refresh.

Comment: Do you have more information? I am having a problem where my templates are being cached and I find out how to refresh them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55568872/django-is-caching-my-site-even-when-caching-is-disabled

Comment: @AndrewSwift you should be able to do a Ctrl + F5 to reload cache

Comment: It's not the browser cache, it's the server that's caching the template. See the question for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Just like the example you mentioned which is using Node and Angular. You can also use Angular with Django and with some techniques like Progressive Web Apps that can be easily added to Angular you can cache the client side templates. In this way the Django server will only be responsible for sending data through a REST API and the cached Angular application/PWA will render data.