# Nginx/Django caching site even when caching explicitly disabled

Tags: django, nginx, caching, virtualenv, uwsgi

I am working on a development site built in **Django** in a **virtualenv** on an **Nginx** server using **uwsgi**.

In the uwsgi config file I have:

```
py-autoreload = 1
```

Most of the time caching is enabled in **settings.py**:

```
CACHES = { 
    'default': {
       'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
       'LOCATION': '/var/www/example.com/cache',
    }   
}
```

but when I am working on the site, I replace the BACKEND and LOCATION lines above with:

```
CACHES = { 
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }   
}
```

The problem I have is that Django or Nginx is caching the site **even when I disable caching and empty the cache**.

It is very strange -- I can actually **delete the main application folder** (not the project folder) and **the site continues to work**.

I ran into this while modifying templates and finding that my updates were not reflected in site content.

I have tried option-reloading in Safari, loading in Chrome, private/incognito windows etc.

The only thing that reliably works is to restart the server.

**Does Django, Nginx, uwsgi or virtualenv have some secret caching system that I don't know about?**

Comment: You need to show your views code. I can't remember what docs I wanted to point at in that answer from 8 (!) years ago, but this is probably not a "caching" issue.

Comment: The views code is like 400 lines long… I'll post the end of it, maybe that will help. Thanks for passing by, anyway!

Comment: does the problem persist if DEBUG mode is on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be either a client-side caching or Nginx caching ;)

(1) in the first case, the browser in not requesting an updated resource because 
it has been told that the previous resource is still valid;

To confirm this, try using Chrome in incognito and see what happens.

If this is the case, I would add the "never_cache" decorator to the Django views:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

class MyView(View):

    @never_cache
    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

or, in a function based view:

```
@never_cache
def myview(request, ...):
   ...
```

Using the "never_cache" decorator, you instruct the browser not to cache the page, 
so whenever the user requires it, he's browser will in turn hit the server.

(2) if not, must be Nginx; check all nginx config files:

- /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
- /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf

and comment out any parameter containing "cache", then restart the service.

I would also turn off "sendfile" as suggested here: https://jeremyfelt.com/2013/01/08/clear-nginx-cache-in-vagrant/

by adjusting file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` as follows:

```
...
html {
    ...
    sendfile off;
    ...
```

Comment: Since you mentioned uWsgi, let's consider that as well as another possible server-side caching actor.
I haven't been using uWsgi for a while (as I normally use either Gunicorn or Daphne in production) so I'm not really aware of that ... just noted that uWsgi documentation talks about caching:

https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Caching.html

Comment: The sendfile modification worked. If you can update the answer to say that sendfile is in /etc/nginx/nnginx.conf I'll choose it as correct.

Comment: Hello Andrew, glad it worked ;) The arrangement of nginx config files can vary slightly, that's why I was so generic. I just updated my answer with a specific example.

Comment: Andrew, on the other hand, I checked my production servers and noticed that "sendfile" is on in nginx config file, but I never suffered this caching issue. That's puzzling. Are you using VirtualBox ?

Comment: I'm not using VirtualBox. The problem has been inconsistent -- I'd already been working on this project for 8 months before I encountered it. In hindsight, it should have been obvious that the issue was at the server level, since Django caching was explicitly turned off, uwsgi was set to reload, and I learned how to refresh browser pages in about 1997.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have to share upper part of your view for more clarification.

But you can try this:

`return render(request, template, {'context':context})`

Comment: I tried that but none of the context variables were passed. I've updated the question with the entire view.